# Problem installing Adobe Reader with wine

Tags: 14.04, wine, adobe-reader

I tried installing Abode Reader and running it using Wine.
While my notepad++ is working fine with wine. But when I tried installing Adobe Reader, it showed the dialog box written

> Set up was interrupted before Adobe Reader could be completely installed.
>   Pleas run the set up again

What to do now.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want install Adobe reader?

Comment: @JulienChau there can indeed be a reason to use Acrobat reader: Some PDFs contain code that can only be read by Acrobat, e.g. for dynamic forms. I had this issue when applying for my drivers licence: The PDF form couldn't be read by any PDF reader I managed to find. Finally I gave up and filled the form on the Windows machine at the optician's where I had my vision test...

Comment: OK i understand.  But have you tried with Master PDF editor ( http://code-industry.net)  You can download a free linux deb file.  I can recommend this program but i am not sure it will solve your specific problem.  It is installed in a few minutes.